# Why are iChat and FaceTime separate programs?

Tags: ichat, facetime

What might be the idea behind this?

Comment: Hang on, lemme just call Steve.

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close this question. This is no the place to speculate on Apple's business strategy. And there's no way somebody will have a definite answer.

Comment: @Loïc Wolff - I can imagine Steve's email response. Something like: "Because they are."

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We can't answer for Apple's decisions. Answers to this will be based on speculation. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First and foremost because they use different protocols.

FaceTime was created as an implementation of a new protocol for video calls. Apple has pledged to release this protocol/format in the future with hopes of other software vendors adopting it so there is opportunity for interoperability.

iChat uses a variety of protocols for chat interaction, most of which were originally designed to carry text as a payload. Video in most cases was something added to these protocols after the fact.

Consider iChat the 'legacy' way of handling video and FaceTime the new way.